# Find Unused case classes in project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, case-class

im working on a huge project which has a lot of old code.
I found manually found some random case classes which are not used in the project and asked myself how many of those exists. 
But I found no method to found them via scalac compiler or via some Intellij magic.

This code often uses sometimes this companion structure

```
object MyCompanionClass{
     final case class TEST(...)
     ...
}
```

Running unused declaration in intellj ofcourse delivers only findings  in java..

Can anyone help?

regards

Comment: For function there are public within a single app/lib, not meant to be used from outside, using package private modifier can be a workaround, as would raise the unused compilation warning

Comment: yes and no.  I agree with you add a private modifier it should be seen by the compiler if the flag is set in compiler options. In my case the  "-Ywarn-unused:privates" is set. And for the sake of a test i added one ghost case class a private modifier. and with a clean/compile the compiler did not catch this case class :S

Comment: As a crude tool, just grep the binary class files.

Comment: `private` != package private, if you restrict the compiler to check only `private` then that's expected